# help: sum of squares summation simplification

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, sums-of-squares

this is my first question, so please don't be too harsh on me.
In order to simplify a standard deviation i have managed to isolate some terms. I'm however unsure of how i can rewrite or simply calculate the term $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i * x_i$ given that i know $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $n$.
$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i * x_i \neq 2*\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, right?

The problem is that i do not know $x_1 ... x_i$ but just the two things. Can it be computed?
Any help appreciated, thanks alot.

Comment: Aside from writing it as $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$, there's not really a nice simplification for the sum of squares of elements in a set or list. I just call it, "the sum of squares".

Comment: Following on from the above comment, your sum now becomes $x_1^2+x_2^2+\ldots+x_n^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of squares is a separate quantity from the sum. Knowing the sum

$$\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$$

doesn't help you figure out the sum of squares

$$\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2.$$

If your $x_j$ are large in magnitude, like $(-100, 200, 100, 0, -200)$, then the sum of squares will be big. If they're smaller, like $(18, -22, 0, 22, -18)$, the sum of squares will be less. If they're all zero, like $(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)$, then the sum of squares will be zero.

But note that all three of these sets have five elements, and a sum of zero.

The only way to figure out the sum of squares from what you're given is to compute it directly.

Comment: I added a bit more to my answer. Glad it helped.

Comment: The sum of the squares cannot be _zero_ for $(20,20,20,20,20)$. I assume you're thinking of variance and forgot to translate things back from variances to raw sums-of-squares.

Comment: GAH! Thanks @HenningMakholm